# Bulk bit.ly creator

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make a bulk bit.ly shorter that reads a list of links from a txt file out outputs the shortened links

The problem is i don't know how to do this and bit.ly has an api restriction if you make links too quickly. I have found that if you make 5 links a second it should work.

how can I shorten 1200 links at once?

```
   <?php

    $sites = array(   
    'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&login=bitlyexample&apiKey=R_8b726077f3d5c6029700c29e529395d3&format=text&longUrl=http://link2.com',
    'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&login=bitlyexample&apiKey=R_8b726077f3d5c6029700c29e529395d3&format=text&longUrl=http://link1.com',
    );

    foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
        $shortened_url = file_get_contents($site);
        if($shortened_url)
            echo "$shortened_url <br/>";
    }
    die();
    ?>
```

Comment: ["The bitly API does not support shortening more than one long URL with a single API call. However, up to 15 URLs can be handled in one API call using the “/v3/lookup,” “/v3/expand” and “/v3/clicks” endpoints."](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiBestPractices#Batch_Processing). That'd be a big improvement, not? Make sure that there's a sufficient delay between each request, because otherwise it's classified as abuse of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep()` after 5 links sleep 5 seconds (or number of seconds the API states):

```
<?php

$sites = array(   
'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&login=bitlyexample&apiKey=R_8b726077f3d5c6029700c29e529395d3&format=text&longUrl=http://link2.com',
'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&login=bitlyexample&apiKey=R_8b726077f3d5c6029700c29e529395d3&format=text&longUrl=http://link1.com',
);
$i = 0;
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    $shortened_url = file_get_contents($site);
    if($shortened_url) {
        echo "$shortened_url <br/>";
    }
    $i++;
    if($i%5 == 0){
         sleep(5);
    }
}
die();
?>
```